Probability distribution required to get clusters of size $\Theta(\Delta^{O(1)})$ in a shattering
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a $(\Delta,\Delta)-$biregular graph on $n$ nodes with a proper coloration. Call a shattering of $G$ subgraphs $G_1, G_2, \dots G_k$ s.t. $(V_i)_i$ is a partition of $V$. The following procedure create a shattering of $G$:
Every node pick a random integer in $[1, 2\Delta]$. For all $i$, $G_i$ is the set of nodes that picked number $i$.
This shattering produce with high probability clusters (connected components of size $O(\log n)$. The basic idea is the following: Consider $v_0$ in a cluster. Imagine yourself traversing the cluster using a spanning tree. Let $A$ be a queue (FIFO) of nodes of the cluster and $A_j$ be the number of nodes in the queue at step $i$. Initially $A = {v_0}$ hence $A_0 = 1$. at each step you remove the first node of the queue and add its neighbors (that haven't been visited yet). Then you have: $A_k = A_{k-1} -1 +Y_k$ where ($Y_k$) is an independent variable. In expectation each node has $1/2$ node in the same cluster hence $(A_k)$ is in average decreasing. Then, an adequate use of Chernoff upper bound gives that $(A_k)$ reach the value $0$ around $k = O(\log n)$, with high probability.
(See this article, subsection "Simple shattering" to see a detailed proof, with the chernoff bound calculus)
I would like to adapt this method to get clusters of size $\Theta(\Delta^{O(1)})$. I tried the calculus with considering numbers picked by vertices are in $[1, N\Delta]$ but I got confused in the process. After thinking a bit, I guess that when $1<N=O(1)$ it should give $O(\log n)$ clusters.
Now I'm wondering if other values of $N$ (with $N=\omega(1)$) would give the desired result; or if I should consider an other distribution somehow. Note that I haven't used so far that $G$ is bipartite; I do not needed it so far, but it might be useful.

Please define what files and clusters are. Are clusters just connected components?

File is an other name for FIFO in french. Clusters are just CC

And what does FIFO mean?

First In, First Out. It's a basic data structure where you can put items in and pull them out. The first item that went in is the first to go out. It's used for many kinds of algorithm. I put a link to the wiki page

Small clusters can't be your only goal, because it is very easy to get $O(1)$ clusters: take the shattering to have two graphs $G_1, G_2$ that are the two sides of the bipartition. Now all components are only one vertex! But if you keep the basic framework (that every vertex picks a $G_i$ independently and uniformly at random) then you'll need the number of subgraphs to grow with $n$ fairly rapidly; maybe $\Delta^{\text{poly}(n)}$ or so.

@MishaLavrov That's completely right. As a matter of fact I'd rather have $\Theta(\Delta^{O(1)})$ clusters. The reason is that I work on an other problem, for which I have an algorithm that solve it on an $n$-sized graph in $O(\log n)$. Hence having clusters of size $\Theta(\Delta^{O(1)})$ means I can solve it on parallel in $O(\log \Delta)$. An other issue that may arise is the total number of clusters that cannot be too high, but I pretend it's not an existing problem for now.
